# How to validate using regex to fit the empty line (no digit) with constraint for Ruby on Rails

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to validate the phone field, telephone1, telephone2, contactNumber for 8 digit and the first digit starting with either 2-3, 5-9.  It works on the validation but it doesn't work if telephone 2 or contactNumber is empty.  How can I set the regex to fit the empty line (no digit) with this constraint?

```
class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  validates :church,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\A[2-3,5-9]\d{7}\z/
  validates :telephone1, presence: true,
                format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :telephone2, presence: false,
                format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :contactNumber, presence: false, 
                format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Thanks

Patrick Lee

Comment: Try `/\A(?:[2-35-9]\d{7})?\z/` if you want your pattern to also match an empty string. I guess you thought the comma separates ranges inside a character class, I removed it since a comma there matches a literal comma. Also, try `allow_blank: true`

Comment: It works.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use the following option (see [this reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)):

```
allow_blank: true
```

> This option will let validation pass if the attribute's value is `blank?`, like `nil` or an empty string for example.

Besides, if you want your regex pattern to match the digits you need OR an empty string, you may enclose the whole pattern with an optional non-capturing group `(?:...)?`:

```
/\A(?:[2-35-9]\d{7})?\z/
   ^^^             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/adjabwVFPr).

I guess you thought the comma separates ranges inside a character class. In fact, it matches a literal comma. Thus, I suggest removing it from the pattern.